# How to get the container log file using docker-py

Tags: docker, containers, docker-logs, python-docker

As part of docker automation am trying to automate certain docker operation using python docker package. Well I have implemented the most of  requirement successfully, But could not find an equivalent method for

```
docker logs <container-id>
```

My implementation:

```
import docker
client = docker.APIClient()
client.attach(container, stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=False, logs=True, demux=False)
```

However it does not give result what am expecting. Kindly help me to identify what is missing in the implementation. Thanks in advance for going through this question

#UPDATE

```
import docker
z=docker.from_env()
dkg = z.containers.get('<container_id>').logs(stream = True, follow = False, tail =10)
while True:
    line = next(dkg).decode("utf-8")
    print(line)
```

Well I have replace my implementation with above one by referring to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825364/8295943). Although it does not work when tail option added. On adding the tail command it is showing blank without any error. Any hint on getting tailed results

Comment: Can you try this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825364/8295943)

Comment: @MustafaGüler I have modified question after trying with above reference. Kindly go through it

Comment: So without tail does it work?

Comment: @MustafaGüler Yes its work. But it hard to work large files. When I went through documentation found this `logs(container, stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=False, timestamps=False, tail='all', since=None, follow=None, until=None)¶`

Comment: @MustafaGüler My ultimate requirement is to docker logs contaner | tail -100 | grep <pattern>